# Get 2 lines yanked or 1 line yanked confirmation

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-mode

This is a small thing, but it still annoys me. When I select at least 3 lines with `V`isual line mode, and then `y`ank them, I get a confirmation: n lines yanked appears at the bottom of my screen. However, if I yank just 1 or 2 lines, no such thing happens.

The same thing happens with `v` and `Ctrl-v`, or something lie `y}` where these confirmations only appear if the selection is spread over at least 3 lines.

Is there a way to turn on these confirmations, now matter how much I yank?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for the [`'report'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27report%27) option:

```
'report'        number  (default 2)
            global
    Threshold for reporting number of lines changed.  When the number of
    changed lines is more than 'report' a message will be given for most
    ":" commands.  If you want it always, set 'report' to 0.
    For the ":substitute" command the number of substitutions is used
    instead of the number of lines.
```

This should solve your issue:

```
:set report=0
```

---

**Edit**

I believe there is no built-in option to issue messages for changes smaller than a line -- you could check the documentation or use the [`:options` command](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#:options) (specially the "messages and info" section). Maybe issuing a message for every change would be distracting for most people.

You will probably need to overwrite the `y` operator to include your custom messages, similar [to the example at `:help :map-operator`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#:map-operator).

Comment: While this partially helps, it doesn't give a confirmation for `vly`, or for `y$` or `y}` when the paragraph ends on that line.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I updated the answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for the more detailed answer. The annoyance is too small for so much work, but at least it is satisfying (in its way) to know no *simple* solution exists. :-)